# Beginner with ocaml types

Tags: ocaml

This is probably a simple question but I'm not sure why I'm getting this error:

I have a type defined in a file

```
type tree = TreeNode of string * tree list;;
```

and I have this function definition in another
[Edit added getFt and getSt functions]

```
let getFt input = match input with
                    | (x, y) -> x;;

let getSt input = match input with
                        | (x, y) -> y;;
let rec traverse input = 
            match (getFt(input)) with
            | "S" -> nodeS (getSt(input))
            | "T" -> nodeT (getSt(input))
    and traverseList input =
            match (getFt(List.hd(input))) with
            | "S" -> nodeS (List.tl(input))
            | "T" -> nodeT (List.tl(input))
    and nodeS input =
            match (getFt(List.hd(input))) with
            | "TRUE" -> (TreeNode("TRUE", []))
            | "FALSE" -> (TreeNode("FALSE", []))
            | "(" -> (traverseList (List.tl(input)))
            | x -> (TreeNode(x, []))
    and nodeT input =
            match (getFt(List.hd(input))) with
            | "not" -> (TreeNode("not", [(nodeS (List.tl(input)))]))
            | "and" -> (TreeNode("and", [(traverseList (List.tl(input)) )]))
            | "or" ->  (TreeNode("or", []));;

let buildAbstractSyntaxTree (input : tree) : tree = traverse input;;
```

and I'm getting this error whenever I compile:
[Edit I put the wrong error]

```
Error: This expression has type Proj2_types.tree
   but an expression was expected of type string * (string * 'a) list
```

Comment: Which line does this error come from?

Comment: The last line where the buildAbstractSyntaxTree has been defined

Comment: It's much easier to help if you give self-contained code. I can't try your code because there's no definition for `getFt`.

Comment: Just added the functions

Comment: Those functions expect pairs as input, but you are applying them to trees.

Comment: But isn't the tree type a pair of input?

Comment: No, a tree is not a pair. It's a completely new type, not equivalent to any other type.

Comment: Then I guess my question boils down to: how do I go about accessing the TreeNode and the Tree list in the tree type? (given a tree type as an input)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I redefined your erroneous functions like this:

```
let getFt (TreeNode (x, _)) = x

let getSt (TreeNode (_, x)) = x
```

After this change, your `traverse` function compiles for me. But there are still problems that will happen if the trees don't have the specific strings you match against.

In other words, your matches aren't exhaustive. This makes the code a bit fragile.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is not aimed at replacing Jeffrey's one but instead at giving you some tips for your further OCaml code.

TL; DR: Strings are "bad"

If I read your code correctly, your tree is a wrapped pair `Treenode of string * tree list` (which looks not really like a tree but more like a path since you don't have a left branch and a right branch, you have a node followed by either nothing or another node etc. Actually you just defined a list ;-))

You start matching on it starting with `traverse`.

`traverse` looks if the first part of the pair is the string `"S"` or the string `"T"` so let's rewrite it:

```ml
let rec traverse = function
  | Treenode ("S", t) -> nodeS t
  | Treenode ("T", t) -> nodeT t
```

What does `nodeS` do? It matches the first part of the head of your list and checks if it's `"TRUE"`, `"FALSE"`, `"("` or anything else. If it's the first two it just creates a new `TreeNode`, it it's the parenthesis it traverses the remaining list and if it's anything else it just creates a new `TreeNode` with it. So you have 3 cases that do exactly the same thing yet you made a case for each of them. Let's rewrite it:

```ml
and nodeS = function
  | [] -> failwith "TODO"
  | ("(", _) :: tl -> traverseList tl
  | (x, _) :: _ -> TreeNode (x, [])
```

As for `nodeT`, we either expect to find `"and"`, `"or"` or `"not"` which gives us:

```ml
and nodeT = function
  | [] -> failwith "TODO"
  | ("not", _) :: tl -> TreeNode("not", [nodeS tl])
  | ("and", _) :: tl -> TreeNode("and", [traverseList tl])
  | ("or", _) :: tl -> TreeNode("or", [])
```

And finally, traverseList:

```ml
and traverseList = function
  | [] -> failwith "TODO"
  | ("S", _) :: tl -> nodeS tl
  | ("T", _) :: tl -> nodeT tl
```

Problems emerge. First, you don't handle empty lists (my `failwith "TODO") but most importantly, you manipulate strings so what happens if you have "A" as your first string? It may be impossible from how you build your tree but it's not shown type-wise. That's where sum types come to help you. Try to redefine your tree like this:

```ml
type node = S | T | True | False | Par | Not | And | Or 
type tree = TreeNode of node * tree list
```

And see where it leads you. OCaml is strongly emphasizing a style guided by types. Strings are useful for text but not types (imagine if you start to add custom functions in your AST, will you match against "myfun of int -> int -> string"? Sounds tedious, wouldn't you agree?)

And I hope you can read my code (and Jeffrey's one) and find how potent pattern matching is in OCaml meaning that you don't have to use your `getFt` and `getSt` functions. Feel free to comment for any question if you have some, people here are happy to help ;-)